# Should I edit my self-deleted answer or create a new one?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Because of a misunderstanding, I posted an answer for a question, then realized my answer was totally wrong. So I deleted it.

After some time I realized that I can actually answer that particular question.

Now, where should I to put my answer? Should I edit the deleted post with the correct answer or should I post it as an another answer, leaving the deleted one as it is.

Which is the better way to go?

Comment: It's not deleted by mod. It's deleted by me. So i can be able to undelete it.

Comment: Even better then! Honestly, that was just the first of several dupe targets I found. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141924/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146618/ and probably a bunch more on various per-site metas. The prevailing wisdom is pretty consistently to edit, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

No need in posting a new answer, just edit deleted answer and undelete it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if there were any actions taken by community.

**If** that post has **no votes,** you can edit it and undelete. If you have deleted it fast enought, not many users has even the oppurtunity to see it.

**However**, if the post has already downvotes, it's better to leave it deleted and post a new one. After the edit, the post would still has downvotes referring to the old version, which would be misleading.

"Potential duplicates" are referring to that situation, when the post was either deleted because of duplicates or by other users. It's (probably) a bit different situation that yours.